# How to loop with pandas: 'for each row in file, for each column in row'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nested-loops

My dataset looks like this:
[image]

and i need to loop through each day, and then each time of the day, and check whether the state is A, B or C. I tried as below, but it doesnt seem to work correctly.. thanks for the help.

```
for row in file.itertuples():
    for j in row:
       if j == 'A'
          *set parameters to certain values*
       if j == 'B'
          *set parameters to other values*
```

Comment: Your statement, "...but it doesnt seem to work correctly.", could you elaborate? To me it looks like your code should work, so what issues are you facing?

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  Images of text are not acceptable, in keeping with the purpose of this site.  "It doesn't seem to work correctly" is not a problem specifciation.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
Any PANDAS tutorial will teach you how to iterate through the entire data frame; what are you doing differently?  What effects do you see?

Comment: See `np.select`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `iterrows()` instead of `itertuples()`, also you need a : after each if.

```
for i,row in file.iterrows():
    for j in row:
       if j == 'A':
          *set parameters to certain values*
          file.iloc[i,'column_name'] = value #for example
       if j == 'B':
          *set parameters to other values*
```